# Best solution for try/except statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch, except

I am wondering if this definition of a try except statement will have the correct behaviour and if there a more robust solution. It is a def to read a power meter and basically If the COM is locked or engaged I wish to implement the second exception block and if the power meter response has a response "glitch" e.g a Value error I wish to implement to first exception block.

```
def get_power_meter():

    try:
        pm = serial.Serial(pm_com_open, 115200, timeout = 1)
        pm.write(b'PW?\r')
        pm_res = pm.readline().decode("utf-8")
        pm.close()            
        return float(pm_res)        

        try:
            pm = serial.Serial(pm_com_open, 115200, timeout = 1)
            pm.write(b'PW?\r')
            pm_res = pm.readline().decode("utf-8")
            pm.close()            
            return float(pm_res)

        except ValueError as e:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(e)

    except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
        message_box_ok(pm_com_open + " is locked...","Please press OK to to restart the software","Aborting...",sys.exit(0),"warning")
```

Comment: You will never reach the second `try:` block, there's a `return` just before it.

Comment: Should I remove it then and just keep the return on the second try block?

Comment: What you want to do isn't really clear. Could you describe it better (without refering to your 'exception blocks', as the behavior you expect from your code is hard to infer from it...)

Comment: So I have a power meter connected to the PC. The definition simply opens the com port and reads the current power meter value. If the power meter is not connected/detected or if its engaged by another application on the COM port I wish to display the message box : "COM X is locked, Please press ok...blah blah"... Under normal operation while logging the values on long timescales there can be "glitches" in the communication on the com port. In this case I wish to raise the Value error exception and try again after 1 second to retrieve a valid float value i.e. valid response from the power meter